# How to link HTML file in python

Tags: python

I have:

```
fruits = [apple, banana, pineapple, oranges] 
sizes = [small, medium, large]
```

I am creating HTML pages having fruitproperties for each fruit and size combination.

Basically my python script creates folders with name:

```
apple, banana, pineapple, oranges
```

and each of the fruit folder has three sub-folders with name:

```
small, medium, large
```

each of these folders contain a HTML file with respective size name. Like

```
small has small.html 
medium has medium.html
large has large.html
```

and it contains the `fruitproperties` for particular `fruit-size combination`.

Thus all the html pages have similar path as below:

```
script-path/fruit/size/size.html
```

Now I want to link all these pages to my HTML index page. But I am new to python and don't know how to make use of path (I can create path with `os.path.join)` using href in python.

Following is my code:

```
def html_home(fruit,size):
    htmlFile = open(fruit+".html","w")
    htmlFile.write("!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<html>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<title> Fruitproperites </title>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<head>")
    htmlFile.write("<body>")
    htmlFile.write("<h1> List of fruitproperties </h1>\n")
    # By the time, I call html_home() function, there is already     
    # respective size.html page been created in each fruit/size folder.
    #  all have path as: scriptpath/fruit/size/size.html 
    scriptpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    htmlpath = os.path.join(scriptpath,target,size,size+".html")
    htmlFile.write('<a href = htmlpath> +size+ '</a>'<br><\n>')  
    htmlFile.write("</body>\n")
    htmlFile.write("</html>\n")
    htmlFile.close() 

    # Following code works fine 
    htmlFile = open('home.html','w')
    htmlFile.write("<!DOCTYPE html> \n")
    htmlFile.write("<html>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<head>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<title> Fruitproperties</title>\n")
    htmlFile.write("<body>\n")
    for fruit in fruits:
        htmlFile.write('<a href="'+fruit+'.html"> List of functions -'+target+'</a><br>\n')
    htmlFile.write("<body>\n")
    htmlFile.write("</html?\n")
    htmlFile.close()
```

can anybody help with linking of size.html in the first half of the code? 
I am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might result from misplaced quotation marks in

```
htmlFile.write('<a href = htmlpath> +size+ '</a>'<br><\n>')
```

It would also create bad HTML.

You should use an other approach to write HTML, a simple on if to use a template string. Strings in Python can go over multiple lines, then you create a context dictionary and use it for string formatting:

```
templ = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Fruitproperites </title>
<head>
<body>
<h1> List of fruitproperties </h1>
<a href="%(href)s">%(size)s</a><br>
</body>
</html>'''
context = {}
context['href'] = 'http://yoursite.tld/'
context['size'] = size
html = templ % context
```

Then write the html content at once as you already did!

To link to a local file instead of a http resource, use the `file:` URI schema. The most easy way to get such a link is to open the file in your browser and check the URL bar.